# Send DNS request with socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, dns

Here is what I am trying to do :

I send a **DNS request** (with dig or whatever), and I intercept it with **socket** in python. Then, I want to send this same request to the gateway, and wait for the response from the gateway.

```
import socket

#I redirected all DNS requests from port 53 to port 2525 so I am listening here
port = 2525
ip = '127.0.0.1'

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((ip, port))

#Gateway part
gateway = '192.168.1.1' 
port_gateway = 9090

sock_gateway = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock_gateway.connect((gateway, port_gateway))

while 1:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(512)

    print(data)
    #send the request from User to the gateway :
    sock_gateway.sendto(data, (gateway, 53))

    reply = sock_gateway.recv(512)

    print(reply)
```

Here is the output : `b'7\xa3\x01 \x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x06google\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00)\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\n\x00\x08\x9b+\xc1\xfa\xf4\xbc\x1c\x14'`

This is the data from the DNS request I made, but then, I want to forward it to the gateway, and to listen to the response, but it doesn't get any response.

How can I do that ?

Comment: And what happens when you query the gateway manually yourself with some DNS query packet? Also, besides learning, what is the purpose you have to get DNS queries and "forward" them? Why not just using a tool that exists and does that properly, like `dnsmasq`?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest first use tools that are already built and debugged.
the DNS lookup tool i use is 
[DNS python](http://www.dnspython.org/)

You will have to grab the request scan through the request for the data you need typically the name of server,  then start up a new request using the DNS libary.

Trying to just forward a request without altering the raw data typically never works.

```
import dns.resolver as dns
gateway = '192.168.1.1' 
port_gateway = 9090

sock_gateway = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock_gateway.connect((gateway, port_gateway))

while 1:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(512)

    ## extract the request 
    request = extract_the_request_data_Fucntion(data)

    gateway_reponse = dns.query(request, source=gateway_server_ip, source_port=port_gateway)

   ## construct responds code goes here
   ##function to parse the responds and send it back to the client
```

writing forwarders is not just extracting the data from the UDP packet and forwarding it,  it almost always requires additional changes.